# How to use ChatGPT to generate huge amounts of test data to fill a database?

Tags: chatgpt

Assuming I have an empty forum, and I want to fill the database with somewhat sensible content for demonstration. Of course, it's possible to just generate thousands of loremipsumeque strings and insert it in database, but it would be obvious that this is not English and makes no sense. What I would like to achieve is:

1. Generate users: each user should have a username and some metadata (possibly only visible to the AI) that defines the style and type of content that this user would generate.
2. Generate topics: pick a random user and generate a random question or call to discussion on a random topic in the style of the chosen user.
3. Generate answers: pick users who are most likely to respond to this topic based on their metadata and generate responses each in the style of each chosen user.

Is it a feasible scenario to use generative AI for this? How likely is such content to be recognized as machine generated? Is the current state of AI good enough to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

LLMs have limits. Some measure their output using "tokens". Some charge users based on the tokens handled. Generating vast amounts of test data require a direct proportion of tokens.

Considering the above, I don't think using an LLM to generate vast data is a good idea. From one side, it's like using a military-grade flame thrower to handle a flies problem. One option is to use a complex and difficult-to-manage power source to complete the task correctly. However, this approach may be more expensive and time-consuming than a commonly known solution.

Comment: Do you mean that generating large amount of data would cost a lot? What if I run an LLM locally?

Comment: @tpimh I suggest you post a new question to either ask for an LLM recommendation (this might help to gauge the community consensus about asking for recommendation questions) or to ask how to do this using a specific LLM (this is more likely to be on topic in the long term).